# How to change from MariaDB back to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I run `select version()` against my MySQl, I get:

```
10.7.3-MariaDB
```

I would like to switch that to instead use this version (to match another instance I have running):

```
5.7.33-log
```

To that end, I have 2 questions:

1. Does a `select version()` result of `5.7.33-log` indicate that db is *not* running MariaDB?
2. How would I revert the `10.7.3-MariaDB` version back to `5.7.33-log`?

Regarding #2, I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235290/3368818) answer, but it's over 10 years old, so  wondering whether it's still valid.

Comment: what operating system are you running?  note that mysql 5.7 will reach end of life in a little over a year, and will no longer get updates to fix security issues.

Comment: My local development environment is Windows. My application itself is running in Linux.

Comment: do you mean the linux subsystem for windows?  or an actual linux vm or server?  if the latter, what linux distribution is it (you will find this in /etc/lsb-release)?

Comment: Is the code running against MariaDB-10.7.3 exactly the same as on 5.7.33? If its using any new features it obviously won't function on 5.7.33. Note the MariaDB-10.7 series also has a [short end of life date 9 Feb 2023](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy), so 10.6 would be a better choice for LTS. As the production environment is more tested now, I'd be looking to update your development environment to match the production.

Comment: I think the short answer is to update the other instance to MySQL 8.

Comment: 3. "Regarding #2", no you won't be able to move a 10.7 datadir containing Aria or InnoDB back to MySQL-5.7 and for it to work. Both formats have MariaDB only items that MySQL-5.7 or 8 won't understand. A logical dump and reimport would be required.

Comment: re #1, yes, 5.7.33-log is mysql, not mariadb.  mariadb release numbers only resembled mysql up through 5.5; after that, mariadb jumped to 10 and mysql to 5.7 and then 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my specific use case.

I'm running MySQL on Windows with MariaDB running on top of that. I need MariaDB for one of my local apps, but plain MySQL for another. I don't need to run the apps concurrently.

With MariaDB running, `select version()` from MySQL Workbench returns  `10.7.3-MariaDB`.

To switch to MySQL by itself, I simply stop my Windows MariaDB service.

Doing `select version()` now shows my MySQL version of `8.0.28`.

Seems pretty straightforward now. I hadn't realized MariaDB can function [alongside](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/) MySQL.